# Chrome Bug, jQuery Fadeout when tabbing windows

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am not sure if this is a bug or not in chrome or just my code;

When i load this animation and do not browse away from the page (i.e. don't go to another tab or so on) the animation runs fine;

But when i tab out of the page this happens:
[image: Chrome Bug]

Tested this on Firefox and it didn't seem to happen here is the process invovled to achieve the same bug:

1. load the page and wait for some animations to appear
2. Tab out of the page for about 5-6 seconds (click around or do something in another tab)
3. Go back to the tab with the animation and watch for a few seconds and you will see the bug (if it is one)

Sorry about that forgot to add the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/7D7Nm/36/

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/7D7Nm/36/show/

Any pointers?

Comment: Hey, Tested with FF4 and it works fine. In Chrome 11.0.696.77 I got the same bug. In Chrome 12.0.742.91 I also get the bug. I did notice that it did right itself after a while?

Comment: i assumed it was CSS but i cant see whats being applied to it ?! it's weird but your getting the error in 12.0.742.91 ?! back to testing then lol, just tested and it seems to be doing the same thing

Comment: Submitted the Issue to Google, thanks for helping me debug

Answer (score 1):

I'm running chrome and I can't repro the error from your instructions. Try upgrading to the latest version of chrome (if you haven't already) and see if that changes anything.

By the way. This is really cool lookin'.

To make this easier to debug, I would write a js pluggin to do what you're trying to do here. Keeping it DRY makes everything easier to debug. You'll then be able to do some extensive testing to see what's actually going on, without having to repeat the tests on each image.

Comment: i did as you advised i upgraded to 12.0.742.91 from 11.0.696.77 and it still doesn't work, & thanks for the compliment :)